# How does a dom element with two css animation work and interact with each others?

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

i'm currently applying two animations to some images. The first one when entering view, the second one when hovering.

```
.Intro {  
  background-image : url('../../img/backgroundWorkshop.svg');
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100vh;
  color: black;
  padding-top : 20vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.AnimationGame1{
  animation: animGame 1 2s ease-in forwards;
}
.AnimationGame2{
  animation: animGame 1 2s ease-in forwards 0.25s;
}
.AnimationGame3{
  animation: animGame 1 2s ease-in forwards 0.5s;
}
.AnimationGame4{
  animation: animGame 1 2s ease-in forwards 0.75s;
}
.AnimationGame img:hover{
  animation: animGameHover 1 10s ease-out alternate;
  position: relative;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 100%;
}

@keyframes animGame {
  0% {
    transform: translateX( -2vw) translateY(1vh);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0) translateY(1vh);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes animGameHover {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(2.5);
  }
    }
```

Problem is when i hover those images, the hover animation start then when it's over the "AnimationGame" class animation start again.

Here is the JSX i'm using react-bootstrap:

```
    <Row className="Intro">
        <Col md={2}>
            <p className="middle">Previous</p>
        </Col >
            <Col sm={6} md={4}>
            <div className="AnimationGame">
                <div>
                    <img src={anim1} className="AnimationGame1"></img>
                    <img src={anim2} className="AnimationGame2"></img>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src={anim3} className="AnimationGame3"></img>
                    <img src={anim4} className="AnimationGame4"></img>
                </div>

            </div>
        </Col>
        <Col sm={6} md={4}>
            <div className="Presentation">
                <h1 className="slideTextTitle">PC Gamer and Web Addict</h1>
                <p className="slideTextPres"></p>

            </div>
            <div className="parcours">

            </div>
            <div className="social">

            </div>
            <div className="suite">

            </div>
        </Col>
        <Col md={2}>
            <p className="right middle">Next</p>
        </Col>
    </Row>
```

Do someone understand why this is happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont see whats wrong actually i tried it myself. Could you maybe add your html?

You can stop an animtion when its done by using `fill:freeze;`

if that doesnt work please add your html because when i use the classes you used it works pretty fine. And maybe explain a bit more at what you want exactly. I would be glad to help you out!

Comment: I edited the post with my JSX, i'm working with react. Unfortunately freeze did not do the trick :s the first animation reload everytime i hover my images, what's more they do not even scale right when the two animations are interacting...Thanks for your help either way.

Comment: I played a bit around with it and what kind of worked was giving the div's around the img a class. I think that if you put a div around every separate image with a class that it will work out :) 
after that you only have to change the class in the hover to your new class instead of "img"
.AnimationGame img:hover{    becomes :  .AnimationGame .(newclass):hover{

Comment: Yeah it works when adding wrapping div and playing with html structure. Thank you gonna validate.